# How to destroy and recreate datatable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have created DataTable, am getting all data from API but I need destroy and recreate every 10seconds am using setInterval function but reload do not reload and every 10second destroy and recreate. Is possible,  I am trying more reference but could not solve this issue and also attached code below please check my code and solve this issue

my code:

```
staffTransaction()

function staffTransaction(){
    var todayDate = new Date();
var dd = String(todayDate.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var mm = String(todayDate.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
var yyyy = todayDate.getFullYear();

to_date = dd + '-' + mm + '-' + yyyy;
    var date = new Date();
    date.setDate(date.getDate() - 7);

    var from_date = date.getDate()+'-'+ (date.getMonth()+1) +'-'+date.getFullYear();
    var offerType = $('#offerType option:selected').val();
    // alert(offerType)
    var transStaff = {
        "admin_id": localStorage.getItem("admin_id"),
        "role": localStorage.getItem("role"),               
        "offer_type": 'znapay',
        "from_date": from_date != undefined && from_date != "" ? from_date : "",
        "to_date": to_date != undefined && to_date != "" ? to_date : "",
        "store_id": localStorage.getItem('store-ids'),
        "branch_id": localStorage.getItem('store_branch')
    }
    console.log(transStaff)
    console.log('Staff' + JSON.stringify(transStaff))
    fetch('https://app/api/v6/manager/transactions-web', {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(transStaff),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'accept': 'application/json'
        },

    }).then(function(test) {
        return test.json()

    }).then(function(callback) {
        $('#transaction-lists').html("")
            $("#transaction-dates").html("Transactions from " + callback.from_date + " to " + callback.to_date)
            var ListTransation = "";
            var transList = callback.transaction_list;
            if (callback.transaction_list.length == 0) {
                $('.not-found').html("<p>Data Not Found");
                ListTransation = "<tr><td colspan='7' align='center'>No Transactions</td></tr>"
                $('#transaction-lists').html(ListTransation);
            } else {
                var mapList = transList.map(function(x, y) {
                    if (y == 0) {
                        localStorage.setItem("last_transaction", x.transaction_id)
                    }
                    var email_help = x.elapsed_time <= 1800 ? "<img src='assets/images/email.png'>" : ""
                    // var email_help = x.elapsed_time <= 1800 ? "<i class='fa fa-envelope-o email-help' aria-hidden='true'></i>" : ""
                    // <i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    ListTransation += "<tr id=" + x.transaction_id + ">";
                    ListTransation += "<td class='reference-id'>" + x.reference_id + "</td>";
                    ListTransation += "<td>" + x.date + "</td>";
                    ListTransation += "<td>" + x.offer_type_label + "</td>";
                    ListTransation += "<td>" + x.offer_class + "</td>";
                    ListTransation += "<td>" + x.store_location + ", " + x.store_city + "</td>";
                    ListTransation += "<td class='bill-amount' style='text-align:center!important'>AED " + parseFloat(x.bill_amount).toFixed(2) + "</td>";
                    ListTransation += "<td>" + email_help + "</td>";
                    ListTransation += "</tr>";
                });
                
                $('#transaction-lists').html(ListTransation);  
                table = $('.staff-transtable').DataTable( {
                    destroy: true,
                    paging: false
                } );
                
                table.destroy();
                setTimeout(function(){
                table1 = $('.staff-transtable').DataTable( {
                    searching: true,
                    retrieve: true,
                    paging: true
                } );
            },2000)
                
                
                 
                
            }
        
    });
}
```

Comment: Alternative suggestion: There should be no need to constantly destroy and recreate the table. Use DataTables built-in support for Ajax, including [`ajax.reload()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()). You may well be able to significantly simplify your logic, this way. For example: no need to build strings of HTML; no need to build a custom "Data not found" message. And probably more.

Comment: thanks for your feedback, am using fetch method but not working please provide fiiddle example

Comment: Right, you already showed us your "not working" `fetch` code. Did you look at the link I provided?